# Error while executing API method: media.videoPlay using trigger.io

Tags: android, trigger.io

I'm trying to play video using trigger.io.
Code is following:

```
    var urlString = "....mp4";
forge.tools.getURL(urlString, function (myUrl) {
    forge.media.videoPlay(
        myUrl,
        function() {
            alert("ok");
        },
        function(content) {
            alert(content)
        }
    );
});
```

When I launch this application using IOS emulator it works. But when I try it on Android emulator I get following errors:

```
[WARNING] Error while executing API method: media.videoPlay
[DEBUG] Returned: {"content":{"message":"Forge Java error: ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat={link}https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/braingasm-video/6bPLY7orbVY.mp4{/link} typ=video/* }","type":"UNEXPECTED_FAILURE","subtype":null,"full_error":"android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat={link}https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/braingasm-video/6bPLY7orbVY.mp4{/link} typ=video/* }
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
at io.trigger.forge.android.modules.media.API.videoPlay(API.java:13)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at io.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeApp.callJavaFromJavaScript(ForgeApp.java:247)
at io.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeJSBridge$1.run(ForgeJSBridge.java:17)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

"},"callid":"BB45C58C-BE4B-42A0-B76A-4EC6B388B850","status":"error"}

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can play videos on the Android emulator, what this error means is there is no app available to play the video. If you run the same code on a device it should use the built in video player.